# UTF-8 encoding in Velocity 1.7 for objects passed from model to view

Tags: java, spring, encoding, utf-8, velocity

In my project I use Velocity 1.7 with Spring MVC 3.1. Below there is source code which shows how velocity beans are configured:

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="contentType" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
    <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="attributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="authentication">
                <bean class="com.myapp.AuthenticatedUserDetails" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Everywhere I use UTF-8 encoding. When I have a static text in a view encoding works perfectly. The problem is when I want to display a value in my .vm template from an object which is passed from the model.

Above I pass authentication object to every velocity template. When I want to use authentication object in view like for example to display authentication.username value I have an encoding issue - special characters are not correctly displayed. For example inside authentication.username there is a value 'Rafał' but when I pass this value to the view the displayed value is 'Rafa?'.

Does someone have a similiar problem? I would be really grateful for your help.

Comment: Can you post some code, e.g. how you process the velocity template in Java code and the relevant bits of the template as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is velocity template code:

```
#set ($username = $authentication.nameAndSurname)

<div id="menuBox">
    <span class="loggedAsLabel">User <b>$!username</b></span>
</div>
```

Here is how view is returned:

```
@Controller
public class UserController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "user-view")
    public String returnView() {
        return "user-view";
    }

}
```

And here is getNameAndSurname method:

```
public String getNameAndSurname() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Object obj = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (obj instanceof User) {
            User user = (User) obj;

            return user.getName() + ' ' + user.getSurname();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I know that this is not a problem with how I retrieve data from database, because from another controller I am able to return data  from DAO with correct UTF-8 encoding as a JSON response.